# QBXML Item Sales Tax vs VAT

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

Hi I'm having an infuriating problem with QuickBooks UK. I am doing an InvoidceAddRq and sending ItemSalesTaxRef:FullName. I have "EGS" in my Item List as a VAT item. I also have EGS in my VAT code list after creating an item for testing. I cannot get it to post as it says:

'There is an invalid reference to QuickBooks Item Sales Tax "EGS" in the Invoice.

QuickBooks UK doesn't use Sales Tax - it uses VAT - nowhere can I find to enter a Sales Tax other than VAT. What do I need to do here to get my invoice posting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below sample code for sales tax

```
<SalesTaxCodeRef>
     <FullName>Standard Sales</FullName>
</SalesTaxCodeRef>
```

Answer (score 1):

For non-US versions of QuickBooks for Windows, you do not use `ItemSalesTaxRef` at all.

Instead, you just use `SalesTaxCodeRef`.

You should be specifying `SalesTaxCodeRef` for every single line item. Do not specify `ItemSalesTaxRef` at all.